# Arithmetics in Android. Need answer fast

Tags: android

I am new to this programming language. So my question is to how to code simple arithmetic or mathematics calculations in Android. And also if possible how to link them to a button and place in a text field (result)..(+-x/)

Thank you in advance

Comment: need more description fast :)

Comment: What other languages do you know? In the end the answer will be the same, it will only be the syntax that differs between languages

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far? so we can help you fast.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic in Java is similar to all other languages for common operators. The Java API also provides a [Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) library for common operations such as abs(), ceil() and floor() as well as trigonometric functions.

As for listening for a button click in Android, see the [UI Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) developer reference. I would recommend the [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) as well as browsing the available [sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample) on the developer website for more information.

Comment: A nice answer for a -3 (and pending) question ;-)